# "Predefined type System.Void is not defined or imported" error trying to compile c# scripts for Unity 2D in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to learn creating 2D videogames with Unity but i can't compile my script for CharacterMovement because of several errors.
Even creating a new empty script, the compiler says that "Predefined type System.Void is not defined or imported" and i couldn't find online a way to fix this.

This is the empty script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyPlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is the script i'm trying to compile :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        if(horizontalMove == 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Jumping", false);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("Jumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
            animator.SetBool("Crouching", true);
        } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
            animator.SetBool("Crouching", false);
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Move our character
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

(On my script i get about 60 errors all similar)

Comment: Try rebuilding your entire solution and closing your visual studio, edit: it worked for me once Clean, Rebuild, and then restart Visual Studio

Comment: I just did it twice and it didn't work both times. Am i missing some library or something like that?

Comment: Which line of code does the error occur on? if at all

Comment: Everytime a void function is defined, the error in the title is raised. On other lines, for example (there are 65 errors...), when i define or use a boolean the error System.Boolean is raised. When i use a float, it's System.Float and so on.

Comment: why do you compile in visual studio? unity is designed to compile the code itself

Comment: Because i don't know how to compile from Unity :)
How can i do it?

Comment: @Ledmington e.g. [build for web](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/building-game) or for [standalone](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/building-game)

Comment: I am using Unity standalone

Answer (score 2):

change the option in **File->BuildSettings->playersettings-api compatibility level** to .Net 4X

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I tried to install `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notification` using `Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications -Version 7.1.2`.

Once I do this, I notice a new config file is added to my solution explorer. I have to delete this to fix the error.

Comment: This wasn't my exact problem, mine was a VS2022 Preview version that dropped a folder into my `.vs` folder called `ProjectEvaluation`.  I have no idea what/why, but I deleted it and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for those stumbling across this in the future: Go to **Edit->Preferences->External Tools->Regenerate project files** to bring back the original CS Project & VS solution files.

That was the only option that worked after trying other common answers like changing API compatibility, upgrading VS, or deleting the project obj folder. I think it broke like that due to me trying to clean out the solution manually and Unity ended up corrupting some packages after I attempted to delete them. So unfortunately it seems you will get this error if you try to do that.

Comment: There is no menu item in edit->preferences

Comment: As of Unity 2021 LTS at least there's still a "Preferences..." option under the Edit dropdown on the Windows version of Unity. In there, under the "External Tools" tab when you have Visual Studio (any version) selected as your External Script Editor, you'll find .csproj options. Under those options is where you'd find the button which regenerates the VS project.